# Ayuda con problema finished with non-zero exit value 1 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema con una APP, me sale este error.

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\SANCHEZ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Aqui adjunto mi Build Gradle. (ya intente volver a instalar todo y nada)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fun.xxxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    // More deps here //
}
```

Comment: Prueba a limpiar el código. Build --> Clean project.

Comment: @Iñigo Irigoyen Erquicia Ya intente limpiar el código. Pero me sigue saliendo dicho error :( .

Comment: Podría ser que te esté chocando la version del sdk (27) con la del tool (28).